# Compiling Zabbix 5.2 with libxml2 support

Tags: xml, linux, compilation, zabbix, debian-buster

I have problem compiling Zabbix 5.2 configured this way:

```
# ./configure --enable-server --enable-agent   --with-net-snmp --with-libcurl --with-libxml2 --with-postgresql --with-prefix=/usr/local/zabbix5 --verbose
...
checking for PostgreSQL libraries... yes
checking if PostgreSQL version is >= 9.2... yes
checking for Zabbix server/proxy database selection... ok
checking for multirow insert statements... yes
checking for pkg-config... no
checking for pkg-config... no
configure: error: LIBXML2 library not found
```

Now I **have** installed `libxml2-dev` (`apt install libxml2-dev`). It does show up as `libxml2-dev:amd64`, not sure why, because the OS is `amd64`.

I tried setting different environment variables, like `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/libxml-2.0.pc` (that's configuration installed by `libxml2-dev:amd64`).

I have no idea why this happens or how can I fix it.

OS: Debian 10 amd64.

Comment: what's in the config.log? you can check the list of dependencies on https://packages.debian.org/buster/zabbix-server-mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue, the problem is the sources I used come from Debian package (`apt source zabbix-server-pgsql`) and they're not sources downloaded from Zabbix site.

It appears this problem happens when building in the usual `./configure; make; make install` manner. However, when I build the Debian package it works OK:

```
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -nc
```

Answer (score 5):

I just successfully installed Zabbix 5.2 from sources on Ubuntu 16.04. I also got the same error as yours even though I installed the `libxml2-dev` package. After a day of searching for solutions, I came up with an idea when looking at the error log:

```
checking for pkg-config... no
configure: error: LIBXML2 library not found
```

Probably because I have not installed the `pkg-config` package. Then I tried to install it and run the configuration command again:

```
sudo apt install pkg-config

./configure --enable-server --enable-agent --with-mysql --enable-ipv6 --with-libcurl --with-libxml2=/usr/bin/xml2-config
```

Surprisingly, the configuration was successful.

Comment: Thank you, but I've had `pkg-config` installed before it, in fact I was using it to try getting libxml2 configuration (unsuccessfully).